# Scooter CDI with variable rev limiter - can it damage ignition?

Tags: ignition, rev-limiter, cdi

I want to limit a delivery scooter with a variable CDI to 45 km/h (which can be unlimited by use of a remote). The dealer said such a limiter wears out the ignition and it's more likely to break.

Is this really true? Because many scooters are limited from factory by CDI. He didn't have a clear answer on that argument, so I'm still not sure if he's right.

[image: Limiter with remote]

Answer (score 0):

You want to fit an external device, but the factory limit may be set in the software in the ecu.

So, the dealer may well be correct, if that external device just controls (shorts or changes) the signal from the ecu.

Comment: There's no limit in ECU or CDI right now. The speed of the scooter is limited through a vario ring. I want to remove that ring, and add the CDI limiter.

If the dealer is right, then why are a lot of scooters limited in the CDI? For a lot of scooters, you'll just have to replace the CDI for an unlimited version. If that's really bad for the ignition, why would they limit it with the CDI?

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely, but not impossible.

Basically, a CDI contains a capacitor, which is charged by the alternator.
A pickup signal indicates the right moment for the ignition, and the CDI discharges the capacitor through the ignition coil.

Racing CDIs generate a higher charge, which results in a stronger, more reliable spark, but puts more stress on the coil and the spark plug.

I doubt that this CDI generates a higher charge, but you never know.

---

Finally, which country is this? 45km/h is the legal limit for small scooters in many countries, and most scooters have limiting CDIs. A CDI with remote control is mainly to fool the police, and as such, illegal in many countries. Maybe, the dealer just wants to deny to build this into the scooter?

Comment: This is for the Netherlands. Maybe the dealer doesn't want to do it indeed, he also told me the device is illegal. I don't really think that's a big problem since the CDI will always be set at 45 km/h.

So technically there's not really a reason why this CDI would wear out the ignition, unless it would be a racing CDI with a stronger spark (which as far as I know, it's not)?

Comment: Correct. As for the legal side: Especially a CDI used to limit the speed _must_ be approved, and this one for sure is not. If you have a crash, you get into all kind of trouble, one of them the insurance not paying. You might plan to never use the remote control. But how  do you prove after a crash, that you didn't use it?

Comment: That's a very good point. Might not be the wisest thing to do.

Thing is that right now the scooter is limited through a ring in the CVT/Vario. This causes the engine to run unnecessary high RPM and thus fuel consumption. If I would remove the ring, the fuel consumption and emission would be less than it is right now. Looking to improve that, without increasing the top speed of the scooter, but there just doesn't seem to be a proper way to do so.